# Is sonoluminescence relevant to the behaviour of Navier-Stokes (or converse)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, singularities, navier-stokes

More precisely, could [Sonoluminescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence) be a singularity of Navier-Stokes(NS)?
Is there some other connection that might be interesting, or is it completely irrelevant?

Wiki page mentions NS, but says it breaks down on small enough scale.

Comment: What do you mean by singularity? Can you be a bit more precise in your second question? Asking if a phenomenon has interesting (to whom? in what regards?) connections (to what?) is so vast that it's impossible to answer here.

What I can say is that the NS equations are based on the hypothesis of continuum mechanics: the underlying molecular structure of the fluid is essentially ignored. Sonoluminescence indeed happens in fluids (collapsing gas bubble in liquid), but the optical phenomena (at least), are outside the scope of NS, because they happen at a much smaller scale.